# Resize Win2D CanvasSwapChain for CoreWindow on XBOX One with C# (NO XAML)

Tags: c#, clipping, xbox-one, win2d

I have been working on a UWP/UWA game for Windows 10/Windows Phone (10) and have been anticipating the Dev Mode for Xbox One. I was excited to hear about the release of the dev mode today and could not wait to get home and test it out on my Xbox.

My app/game runs great, I have not encounter any errors (yet) aside from the drawn area being clipped (outer edge outside of "titlesafe/tv safe" region).

I am using a Win2D CanvasSwapChain and a generic CoreWindow.

I feel like there is something I can do with the MyCoreWindow or MyViewSource to alleviate this issue but have not found the answer yet. It may be the lack of sleep at this point but I am hoping an answer or an arrow pointing to it would be of great help to myself and future seekers.

I would prefer to not use xaml.

Here is my View code.

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;          
class MyViewSource : IFrameworkViewSource
{
    public IFrameworkView CreateView()
    {
        return new MyCoreWindow();
    }
}
```

And this is the MyCoreWindow

```
class MyCoreWindow : IFrameworkView
{
    private IGameSurface _surface;
    private Engine _gameEngine;

    public void Initialize(CoreApplicationView applicationView)
    {
        applicationView.Activated += applicationView_Activated;
        CoreApplication.Suspending += CoreApplication_Suspending;
        CoreApplication.Resuming += CoreApplication_Resuming;
    }

    private void CoreApplication_Resuming(object sender, object e)
    {
        _surface.Resume(sender, e);
    }

    private void CoreApplication_Suspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        _surface.Suspend(sender, e);
    }

    private void applicationView_Activated(CoreApplicationView sender, IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Activate();
    }

    public void Load(string entryPoint)
    {
        _surface.Load(entryPoint);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        while (_gameEngine.IsRunning)
        {
            Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher.ProcessEvents(CoreProcessEventsOption.ProcessAllIfPresent);
            _surface.Update();
            _surface.Draw();
        }
    }

    public void SetWindow(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow window)
    {
        _surface = new Surface(window);
        _surface.SetFrameRate(60);
        _surface.SetUpdateRate(100);

        _gameEngine = new Engine(_surface.CanvasDevice);

        _surface.AddComponent(_gameEngine);
    }

    public void Uninitialize()
    {
        _surface.Unload();
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CoreApplication.Run(new MyViewSource());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run without XAML, your swapchain is the only thing rendering graphics, so it always fills the entire screen.  To have the swapchain scaled to fit only inside the title safe area, you would need to feed it as input to some other composition system (which could be XAML or the Windows.UI.Composition APIs) that can scale and translate your image while filling in the borders with a background color.

You could draw to just a selected subset of your Win2D swapchain by setting CanvasDrawingSession.Transform to scale and offset your rendering, plus using CreateLayer to clip it.

It's usually better for games to draw even outside of the title safe area, though.  Exactly how much of this space is visible will differ from one TV to another, so if you just leave it black, some players will see ugly black borders around your game.  You can't draw important stuff that is needed for gameplay in this region, because other players won't see that at all, but typically you would want non-essential background graphics to extend all the way to the real edge of the screen.

(this is one of the nuisances of developing content for TV displays)